# How to remove lines and characters from listings / tcolorbox?

Tags: listings, tcblisting

Consider this MWE

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\PassOptionsToPackage{final}{listings}
\usepackage[%
  ,listings
]{tcolorbox}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{%
  style     = {mystyledef},
}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyledef}{%
  morecomment  = [l][\nullfont]{\%<},
  deletecomment  = [is]{\%<}{>},
}

\newtcblisting{codeexample}[3][]{%
  listing only,
  listing style=mystyle,
  title={#3},
  label = #2,
  #1,
}

\begin{document}
%<*driver>
XXX
\begin{codeexample}{md:metadata:title}{all}
%</driver>
%<*example>
Some text
%</example>
%<*driver>
\end{codeexample}
XXX
\end{document}
%</driver>
```

which gives me

[image]

---

Question:

> **How do I get rid of the `*` and the additional (blank) lines before and after the text?**

Comment: When I compile your MWE, the `<` and `>` still appear in the tcolorbox, but the words "driver" and "example" seem to be replaced with empty space.

Comment: Just tested the MWE again (TL 2020, LuaLaTeX), image still looks the same.

Comment: Interesting. I'm using `pdflatex`