# How to replace the "space symbol" (squat-u) in listings?

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, tcblisting

Instead of this output with a "squat-u" space symbol

[image]

I would like to replace it with e.g. `$\cdot$`. It is no problem to replace the default symbol for tabs but not for spaces??

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{final}{listings}
\usepackage[%
  ,listings
]{tcolorbox}


\newtcblisting{codeexample}{%
  listing only,
  listing options = {%
    showspaces=true,
    showtabs=true,
    tab=\rightarrowfill}
}

\begin{document}
XXX
\begin{codeexample}
Some text with spaces between words.

    "what is a space"?
\end{codeexample}
XXX
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to redefine `\lst@visiblespace`:

```latex
\def\lst@visiblespace{\lst@ttfamily{\char32}$\cdot$}
```

> [image]

Full code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{final}{listings}
\usepackage[%
  ,listings
]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\def\lst@visiblespace{\lst@ttfamily{\char32}$\cdot$}
\makeatother

\newtcblisting{codeexample}{%
  listing only,
  listing options = {%
    showspaces=true,
    showtabs=true,
    tab=\rightarrowfill}
}

\begin{document}
XXX
\begin{codeexample}
Some text with spaces between words.

    "what is a space"?
\end{codeexample}
XXX
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much – maybe you have an idea for https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/487994 , too? Thanks!

Comment: @LukasCB You're welcome :-) About your other question, I looked ad it, but I don't know how to solve it, sorry. I must say that for me the `<` and `>` are printed as well (https://i.stack.imgur.com/V49hW.png) which is rather odd.